# JavaScript / Jquery click event on IE8 is not working properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, click, jquery

I'm a newbie in web development.

I'm having some issues on the buttons of my project.
This line of code is working in all web browsers, except for IE8:

```
$("#SampleBtn").live("click", function(){
     console.log('It works!');
});
```

It doesn't respond the way it should be when clicked. In the example, it's supposed to print "It works!", apparently nothing happens. However, if the user clicks on the button without letting go (keydown) for more than 1 second, it works.

I'm not really sure if where the problem is coming from. Does it have something to do with the .live or the click event?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `live` method was deprecated in 1.7 and **removed** in 1.9. What version are you using? The alternative is to use `on`.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `$.fn.jquery` in the console to find out. Also with IE the console object does not exist until the developer console is open. If you try to access console before that time you will get an error.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.2. I tried 'on' but now, it doesn't even work in Chrome

Comment: Is the click binding inside the `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: @Barmar - in this case it would actually not matter if it's inside of document ready or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found out that locally, there's no problem with the buttons, however, when the app is run in our node.js server, that's where the issue occurs. 
This was causing the bug on IE8:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.png',sizingMethod='scale');
```

It seemed that the preloader is causing the delays on the customized button image's response. Perhaps, it takes time before the images are being fetched.
Anyways, we were able to fix this issue by changing to:

```
 background-image: url('images.png');
```

But thank you all for taking time sharing your ideas on this. :)

Answer (score 1):

IE8 has quite a few issues but this should definitely work. My best guess is the console.log call is failing (for the reason I mentioned in the comments).

Try changing `console.log` to an `alert` and see if it works.

Also try using the [delgated version of on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#SampleBtn', function(){
     console.log('It works!');
});
```

Comment: The console.log doesn't have any issue. Anyway, I'm going to update our app on our server using your answer. Hopefully it works

Comment: You only need the delegated form if the button is added to the DOM after the binding is created. If it's a static element, your original code should work.

Comment: This is true, and not using the delegated form is more preformant and resilient in the situation where you have only a handful of elements to bind. That being said, I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that @Kimpoy was using the delegated live binding for a reason.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, our server is using 1.7.2. So, .live would still have to work, right? I mean, it is working but only if you push the buttons a bit longer, not just clicking it in a snap.

Comment: @Kimpoy it should work with either. `live` has nothing to do with how long a button is clicked. it means that the event is set up once on the document and any click event that bubbles up originating with a #SampleBtn will trigger your function. The bubbling is nearly instantaneous so that would not be the source of any lag.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer. Yes, I thought about that, too. It should have worked regardless of which is being implemented, however, there has to be some reason why it isn't working well. Hitting the button with a quick click doesn't do anything, but if you push it for a little while, more like at least a second or two, it does work. IE8...you're killing me! LOL

Comment: What's the markup for `#SampleBtn`? I remember IE8 has some bugs around live bindings (and is actually very slow with them) also make sure to read [the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn)